# Batch file to add network printers to any Linux system

Tags: linux, batch-file, printing, terminal, console

So, I have looked everywhere, yet can't seem to find anything useful. 
Is it in any way possible to write a batch file to install 4 networked printers on a Linux system? Imagine a large company with people walking in and out having to use the printers. Simply running the file should add 4 networked printers and install the drivers. Is this possible?

Comment: It is possible, but to provide an answer to your question some details might be useful: e.g. do you use CUPS and if not, what spooler do you use? And so on, and so forth.

Comment: Why batching that?  Are you planning to do that more than once?

Comment: The batch script should provide all neccesairy installs, as it will indeed be used for a 100-ish laptops. If possible, it should be independent from previous installs on the system. So if CUPS is needed, also installing CUPS. 
The used printers are 2x RICOH Aficio MP 8001 PCL 6, a Gestetner MP 4002 PCL 6 and a HP Color LaserJet CM2320 MFP Series. Also, it should add it to the waiting line of the printer, not printing right away. I really have no idea if it is possible.

Comment: For Windows, I used the `CScript %windir%\System32\PRNMNGR.vbs -ac -p "\\server\printer"` and I am looking for something similar in Linux.

Answer (score 0):

From My experience with Batch, batch is only for Windows based operating systems, unless you have a windows shell, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12680998/run-bat-in-linux-environment) for more details.

Comment: Doesn't have to be a .bat though, any script that will perform this would be nice :-)